# build.sbt configuration to add external java files using sbt packageSrc

Tags: java, package, sbt

I am using sbt-xjc plugin to generate java classes from XSD files. The plugin generates these classes under `project/target/scala-2.10/xjc` directory. 
I need to create 2 jar files one with all .class files and another with all .java source files.
I am able to generate the jar file that has all .class files using `sbt package` but the issue is with `sbt packageSrc`, this command is looking only for folder those are in `project/src/java folder` and not considering files those are generated by sbt-xjc plugin under `project/target/scala-2.10/xjc`. Is there any configuration that i can provide that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know why this happens the command `inspect tree packageSrc` is helpful, it will also tell you what to change to have your sources included.

When executed should show you something like this:

```
> inspect tree packageSrc
[info] compile:packageSrc = Task[java.io.File]
[info]   +-compile:packageSrc::packageConfiguration = Task[sbt.Package$Configuration]
[info]   | +-compile:packageSrc::mappings = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Tuple2[java.io.File, java.lang.String]]]
[info]   | | +-compile:unmanagedSources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | | +-compile:unmanagedResources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | | +-compile:unmanagedResourceDirectories = List(/tmp/q-23437043/src/main/resources)
[info]   | | +-*:baseDirectory = /tmp/q-23437043
[info]   | | +-compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories = List(/tmp/q-23437043/src/main/scala, /tmp/q-23437043/src/main/java)

// more stuff but not relevant for us
```

You can see from there that SBT is using **`mappings`** key to know from where to take the files.

Knowing that we can take the generated files and add them to the mappings in `packageSrc` in your `build.sbt`:

```
import Path.flat

xjcSettings

def xjcSources(base: File) = base ** "*"

mappings in Compile in packageSrc ++= xjcSources((sourceManaged in (Compile, xjc)).value) pair flat
```

You can read more about [Mappings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html) and [Paths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html) to customize / control the result.